# A simple question on continuous functions

Tags: general-topology

Let me ask a simple question on continuous functions.

Let f be a continuous function from R to R.

$ f:X\rightarrow Y$

$f(5)=0$ and $f(6) = 1$

Then can you expect that:

for all y in the open interval $(0,1)$,

some $x∈(5,6)$ exists such that $f(x)=y$.

If some points are unclear, let me correct them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you write that $f$ is a function from $R$ to $R$ and just after that $f: X\to Y$? That last means that $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I am very sorry. I thought it helped us to distinguish the domain R from the range R although the two are same.

Comment: It might, but you never use this distinction again anyway.

Comment: I won't. It made readers more confused.

Comment: Yes, you can. It is [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is just an extension of the Intermediate value theorem which states:If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $y$ is such that $f(a) \leq y \leq f(b)$, then there exists $x \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x)=y$. 
Hence we can conclude:
$$\forall y \in (f(5),f(6)), \exists x \in (5,6)\ \text{such that} f(x)=y.$$

Answer (score 0):

Restriction of a continuous function is continuous. So, $f:[5,6]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Now by the intermediate value theorem, for any $x\in (f(5),f(6))$, there must be some $c\in [5,6]$, such that $f(c)=x$. Now note that $c\in (5,6)$.